# In DBX i am not able to step into a particular function?

Tags: dbx

In dbx i have a put a break on a particular function using stop.Like stop function. But it is not stopping there instead when i try to step in using step command I get this error

```
after line 17745:       (noname) = @0xf1deaa3c
```

What could be the problem???

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize that output message.  I can't guess what the message is likely to mean. Could you tell us what OS you are using?  Is it Linux or Solaris or something else?  What is the version of dbx?